# How to transpose a text file on character basis

Tags: text-processing, utilities

There are some tools like `datamesh` to transpose a matrix in a `csv` file, but I want to exchange rows and columns character based. So a file

```
abcde
fghij
klmn
opqrs
```

should become

```
afko
bglq
chmq
dinr
ej s
```

Note that as line 3 is shorter, a whitespace has to be inserted in the last row.

Of source I could write some C program to do it, but I thought I once met a tool to do this, but my search engine doesn't help me find it.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with the `rs` utility in pure transpose (`-T`) mode - if you space the input appropriately first i.e.

```
$ sed -e 's/./& /g' -e 's/ $//' file
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n
o p q r s
```

(or, if you have GNU sed, you can use `sed 's/./ &/2g'`; another option is using a loop `sed -E ':a; s/([^ ])([^ ])/\1 \2/; ta'`); then

```
$ sed -e 's/./& /g' -e 's/ $//' file | rs -Tng0
afko
bglp
chmq
dinr
ej s
```

The important options are:

- `-T` pure transpose
- `-n` pad null entries
- `-g0` set the output gutter width (inter-column spacing) to zero

Alternatively, doing the input splitting using `awk` with an empty input field separator and default output field separator:

```
awk '{$1=$1} 1' FS= file | rs -Tng0
```

Comment: Or add the space before each character: `sed -e 's/./ &/g' file | rs -Tng0`.

Comment: The only problem is that this depends on the count of characters of the first line. Try changing the first line (only) to `abc`.

Answer (score 2):

A general solution for transposing with awk follows.

To work correctly we need the number of columns.
That could be found while reading the file into an array of values:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=i4
delimiter=""
sep=""

transpose() { : # comment sed for newer awks.
              # Do this to separate characters in quite old awk
              # very old wak does not allow that the FS could be Null.
              #sed -e 's/./ &/g' "$file" |
              awk ' 
                   { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a[NR,i]=$i};{(NF>m)?m=NF:0} }
                   END { for(j=1; j<=m; j++)
                         { for(i=1; i<=NR; i++)
                           { b=((a[i,j]=="")?" ":a[i,j])
                             printf("%s%s",(i==1)?"":sep,b)
                           }
                           printf("\n")
                         }
                       }
                   ' FS="$delimiter" sep="$sep" cc="$countcols" <"$file"
             }

transpose
```

With this file:

```
abc
fghij
klmn
opqrs
```

Will print:

```
afko
bglp
chmq
 inr
 j s
```

Awk takes care of separating the characters if the "field separator" is null.
The characters are printed in one line if the variable `sep` is also null.

---

If the awk available is an older one, a null FS is not valid. Use the following two commands.

To count the number of characters, use this in older awks:

```
# Work with any POSIX awk to find the max character count in all rows.
countcols=$(awk '{l=length($0);(l>max)?max=l:0}END{print max}' < "$file")
```

To do the transposition, an space could be added in front of each character and use an space as a "field separator" and avoid the empty FS:

```
sed -e 's/./ &/g' < "$file" |
awk ' {for(i=1;i<=cc;i++){if($i==""){$i=" "};r[i]=r[i]sep$i;};sep=""};
      END{for(i=1;i<=cc;i++)print(r[i])}
    ' cc="$countcols"
```

Comment the sed line for newer awks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `cut` and `paste`. As you don't have any delimiter like space or tabulator it need some fixup with `sed`:

```
for COL in {1..5}; do cut -c $COL < infile | paste -s -d_ ; done | sed -e 's/__/_ /g' -e 's/_//g'
```

Here broken up in multiline:

```
for COL in {1..5}; do
  cut -c $COL < infile | paste -s -d_
done | sed -e 's/__/_ /g' -e 's/_//g'
```

The output of the first part looks like:

```
for COL in {1..5}; do cut -c $COL < infile | paste -s -d_ ; done

a_f_k_o
b_g_l_p
c_h_m_q
d_i_n_r
e_j__s
```

One annoying thing is that you have to know how many columns there are before start.

Comment: This fails if you change the first line to less characters, say `abc`.

Answer (score -1):

If lines with less characters, pad each line with some character and then remove the extra characters.

echo abc | sed 's/./&@@@@/' | sed -r 's/(.{4})./\1/'

abc@

echo "" | sed 's/./&@@@@/' | sed -r 's/(.{4})./\1/'

@@@@

Comment: (1) Your commands don't give the results that you say they do. (2) Even if the results that you show were correct, how would this answer the question?